# Natural numbers product property

Tags: set-theory

To prove the following $$m < n \iff lm < ln$$

where $l, m, n ∈ $ the naturals defined in the von Neumann construction

where $m<n$ is defined as $m$ being strictly a subset of $n$

and where $lm=p_l(m)$ by the recursion theorem. I can prove this by induction which takes about 10 lines, but I feel like there is a much shorter proof to this identity. Am I right in my suspicion?

Comment: Well, first of all 'length of proof' is a terribly ill-defined problem in everyday mathematics. Secondly, if your question is whether there is a more, for the lack of a better word, 'elegant' proof than yours, the first step to be able to even address your question is to show us your proof.

Comment: Also, the notation $p_l(m)$ is not standard -- at least it's not clear to me which style of definition it's supposed to refer to. You probably ought to present that definition in more detail.